# Glass Fish - practical limits in throughput and mesasge size?

Tags: glassfish, limits

Not a glassfish specialist here but in a project where GlassFish is to be used as enterprise service bus, and I am sort of on the receigving end and a little no agreeing with the architecture team.

What are practical limits on throughput (messages per second) and message size for GlassFish? Just as house numbers for a decent modern dedicated server. Asking because the architectural proposal on my desk is IMHO ridiculous - but I have no idea about the limits of GlassFish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should run your own benchmark yourself (on your hardware, with your own settings) but to my experience, GlassFish ESB is pretty efficient, and reliable.

Just in case, here are some resources that might give you some ideas:

- [Benchmarking BPEL Service Engine](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=BpelPerformance.html)
- [BPEL SE Scalability Experiments/Evaluations](http://wiki.open-esb.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=BPSEScalabilityTesting)
- [Benchmark Glassfish ESB April 2010](http://www.pymma.com/eng/IT-Tech-Papers/Pdf-folder/Benchmark-Glassfish-ESB-April-2010)

But if you need to convince someone, you should IMO come back with demonstrable facts.

Comment: Owning is not possible - main problem is that we talk LARE company here. This is an archivtecture decision that is imposed on us, hardare is "unknown" (enterprise service bus - just use it type of decision) and not maintained by our project.